# Javascript - selecting and .click()

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to automate a click when visting a website. This is the HTML I'm looking at.

```
<div class="box_wrapper">
     <a id="itemcode_11094414" class="box">7.5</a>
     <a id="itemcode_11094415" class="box">8</a>
     <a id="itemcode_11094416" class="box">8.5</a>
</div>
```

when I select the size, say for instance size 8, the class= tag turns to "box active" like so,

```
<div class="box_wrapper">
     <a id="itemcode_11094414" class="box">7.5</a>
     <a id="itemcode_11094415" class="box active">8</a>
     <a id="itemcode_11094416" class="box">8.5</a>
</div>
```

How can I go loop through the class and select a desired size? Also, I was just tinkering around and noticed that I had a hard time simulating a click on the add to cart and other buttons. For the add to cart the HTML looks like this,

```
<div class="add_to_cart">
    <div class="add_to_cart_left">
        <img id="add_to_bag_btn" alt="Add To Bag" src="/images/add_to_bag.gif"></img>  
        <img id="add_to_bag_btn_processing" alt="" src="/images/add_to_bag_processing.gif"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this the correct chunk of HTML I should be looking at for a simulation of a click?

Comment: Post your javascript.

Comment: How are you running Javascript on sites that you're visiting? Are you trying to write a browser extension?

Comment: Are you free to use jQuery?

Comment: I'm trying to run through either scriptish or even as far as writing an extension. I don't have a lot of experience with jQuery but I'd be excited to see how it can be implemented.

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript or jQuery for that matter, I would recommand you use jQuery for something like this. Also I see you are using </img> I don't think that is necessary, you may also change your buttons like this "<input type="image" src="/images/add_to_bag.gif" />" this way you will be able to use for example onClick() if you decide to go with Javascript.. There is many ways you can do this. You need to pick one, try it, if you get stuck ask for help and provide sample of your javascript / jQuery code.

Comment: You can use this as references task you are trying to accomplish are quite basic, URL#1 http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter URL#2 http://www.jquery.com

Comment: +1 for jQuery. If you can't use jQ, you could, among other things, add an inline javascript click handler to each anchor tag, or have a more global onClick handler that searches for the clicked element.

Comment: @LJ-C Read this before using 'schools again: http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: @Daedalus interesting read, I  guess you learn something new ever day!

Answer (score 1):

Since it's Christmas and you sounded excited to see jQuery in action I created a fiddle for you.  Here is a sample of what you (could) want using jQuery:  http://jsfiddle.net/akkJ5/2/

The code for selecting sizes and twiddling active classes is as follows:

```
var selectedSize = '';

$(".box").click(function(){
    $(".box").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    selectedSize = $(this).html();
    $("#messages").html(selectedSize +" was selected");
});
```

In it I create an event listener for clicks on all **box** class elements.  Since only one should be active I remove the active class from all **box** class elements then add *active* to the clicked box.  I save the innerHTML of the selected link as selectedSize, and write it to an element for display sake.

In terms of simulating a click on a button you could do something like this:

```
$(".add_to_cart").click(function(){
   alert('cart clicked'); 
});

$(".add_to_cart").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

To attach event to all the classed you can do

```
var selectedvalue = ''; 

for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('box').length; i++ ) {
    var d = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[i];
    d.onclick = function (e) {    
       selectedvalue = this.text;
       this.className = this.className + " active";
    }
}
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/Nv8t2/2/

---

To navigate through classes and add your class to the link that has same value

**JS**

```
var value = 8;
for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('box').length; i++ ) {
    var d = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[i];
    if(d.text == value) {
         d.className = d.className + " active";
    }
}
```

To simulate the click handler for the add to cart you can enclose them to

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc();">
<img id="add_to_bag_btn" alt="Add To Bag" src="/images/add_to_bag.gif"></img>
</a>
```

If you want to send it some link update this `href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc();"` to `href="your_link"`

Check http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/Nv8t2/1/

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful and easily understood. But going over the code, this seems as though its just concatenating the string. I want to actually simulate a click because when I go to press the add to cart button, the proper size isn't selected.

Comment: updated the answer to attach click event on every box class and on click assign its value to selected value